# Efeito máquina de escrever não atribui o que eu quero corretamente

Tags: javascript, html

bom eu fiz um efeito da máquina de escrever e preciso que o texto passa por seção pra cada atribuição da sections. Ao invés de pegar todos os textos passar ao mesmo tempo, o texto passa o primeiro depois quando terminar passar para outra seção respeitando o time e assom passsando para o outro texto.

```js
function typeWriter(elemento) {
    const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
    elemento.innerHTML = '';
    textoArray.forEach((letra, i)=> {
        setTimeout(() => {
            elemento.innerHTML += letra
        }, 95*i)
    });
}
const titulo = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
Array.from(titulo).forEach(typeWriter);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
    <title>Maquina de escrever</title>
  </head>
<body>
<section class="section1" id="Estudos">
      <h3>Meus conhecimentos de Programação</h3>
    </section>

    <section class="section2" id="Projetos">
      <div>
        <h3>Meu projeto de Front-end</h3>
      </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

tudo bem , no seu caso acredito que seja na linha que você seleciona a sua TAG h3 com querySelectorAll utilize [] chaves para selecionar o item separadamente como[0] para pegar o primeiro h3, e o segundo armazena em outro const

const titulo = document.querySelectorAll('h3')[0];
Array.from(titulo).forEach(typeWriter);
const titulo2 = document.querySelectorAll('h3')[1];
Array.from(titulo2).forEach(typeWriter);

Obs: desculpe responder desta forma pois estou respondendo pelo telefone.
Me dê um feedback se consegui lhe ajudar. valeu

Answer (score -1):

Kk descobri outra forma, tenta essa primeiro

Deixa só uma const para o título e chama a função duas vezes separado assim como abaixo, vê se vai funcionar

Array.from(titulo[0]).forEach(typeWriter);
Array.from(titulo[1]).forEach(typeWriter)

Comment: bom eu esqueci de colocar o <p> rbm ou h2 seja o que for mais em cada seção fui colocar aqui dessa forma não pegou